# I can't understand what is the red line code is want to say

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7HzE.png)

hello guys
I didn't understand the red line mark coed why it is used in this code.
is their any other alternate code we can use instead of that.

Comment: Add `required` ==> `CategoryCard(required this.icon, required this.name)`

Comment: That's a constructor which instantiate your class with values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CategoryCard` class declared icon and name. Using constructor you can initiate it.
Red line code indicates the `constructor` with `values`.
You can make it `nullable` or `required` as per your requirement.

For `Required` ::

```
class CategoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final String name;
   CategoryCard({Key? key,required this.icon,required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          icon,
          Text(name)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For `Nullable` ::

```
 class CategoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
      final Icon? icon;
      final String? name;
       CategoryCard({Key? key,this.icon,this.name}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              icon!,
              Text(name!)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`CategoryCard` class declared icon and name. Using constructor you can initiate it.
Red line code indicates the `constructor` with `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
class CategoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final String name;
   CategoryCard({Key? key,required this.icon,required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          icon,
          Text(name)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```